# Descriptive position in document like "in the middle, at the top" etc

Tags: macros, positioning

In a math book (which is written in a nice, more or less informal tone) from which I don't know if it was really written in LaTeX I found something very interesting. In the text there was written something like "quite at the end of page 84 you will find...".
I was pretty astonished. If this would be hard-coded then it appears to me risky. Some more lines before and it might go to the top of page 85. So I asked myself if this could be coded somehow in LaTeX in a way like this,

1. find out the page number and the number of lines of a page (= N)
2. determine the position of a label on this page
3. use a case dependent text block: "in the beginning of page" if line number under 37 percent of N, "in the middle of page" if line  number between 37 percent and under 63 percent, "at the end of page" if line number between 63 and 100 percent

Something like this... Does that work?

Comment: sure, you can save the absolute position, e.g. with zref and \zsavepos.

Comment: I have not used this technology, but many others here have used it. LaTeX creates an auxiliary file (extension *.aux), which may contain information written there, as the document is being compiled. That information is read back, on the next compile. So you can modify something (such as page number where to find an object) on the second run, if you write where it was placed on the first run. If this sounds useful, search on this site for how to do it.